# In local Firebase, how do I set a projectId for the current environment?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I'm trying to write some test data to a local version of Firebase.  I have these variables defined in my .env.local (and .env.development files) ...

```
REACT_APP_MB_ACCESS_TOKEN="accesstoken"
ALGOLIA_APP_ID="appid"
ALGOLIA_API_KEY="apikey"
NODE_ENV="development"
FIREBASE_EMULATOR_HOST_VAR=localhost:9000
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
GCLOUD_PROJECT=mutualaid-123f6
```

I have the below set up (via npm run dev:upload) to upload dummy data into my local Firebase ...

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const data = require("./data.json");
let serviceAccount = process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET;
...

  require("dotenv").config();
  admin.initializeApp();
  db = admin.firestore();
...

async function upload(data, path) {
  console.log("starting ...");
  return await db
    .doc(path.join("/"))
    .set(data)
    .then(() => console.log(`Document ${path.join("/")} uploaded.`))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(`Could not write document ${path.join("/")}.`);
      console.log(e);
    });

S
```

adly the above results in

```
...
Could not write document organizations/1/missions/aaf3c03c33ecf79e3d7ffddf401c01f0.
Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment. 
To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit: 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
    at /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/resilience-app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:89:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

f
```

or all data in my data.json file (examples of it are below).  What else do I need to configure to get this data into my local Firebase?

```
{
  "organizations": {
    "1": {
      "missions": {
        "aaf3c03c33ecf79e3d7ffddf401c01f0": {
          "status": "started",
          "missionDetails": {
            "dummy": "This is only here because upload modules did not understand that we want this to be a field",
            "needs": [
              {
                "name": "Fruits & Veggies Medley",
                "quantity": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "uid": "aaf3c03c33ecf79e3d7ffddf401c01f0",
          "deliveryConfirmationImage": "",
          "feedbackNotes": "",
          "groupUid": "Daly City 2020/03/05",
          "organizationUid": "1",
          "volunteerDisplayName": "Michael Williams",
          "deliveryWindow": {
            "timeWindowType": "as soon as possible",
            "startTime": "06/03/2020, 10:40:57"
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed your config object to `admin.initializeApp`

Since you use dotenv to load env files, you can create a config object with env details like

```
const config = {
    type: "service_account",
    project_id: "xxx",
    credential: 'your credentials'
};

require("dotenv").config();
  admin.initializeApp({config});
  db = admin.firestore();
```

If you are not passing any config to initializeApp then you need to define it **FIREBASE_CONFIG** env object.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup):

> The SDK can also be initialized with no parameters. In this case, the
>   SDK uses Google Application Default Credentials and reads options from
>   the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable. If the content of the
>   `FIREBASE_CONFIG` variable begins with a { it will be parsed as a JSON
>   object. Otherwise the SDK assumes that the string is the name of a
>   JSON file containing the options.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be missing `process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET` (unless you've purposefully not included it since it's a private key). I should also point out that `.env*` files are not suitable for storing private keys since they are bundled in your application code and are publicly accessible.

There are a couple of ways that you can initialise the admin SDK. They are outlined on the [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) reference guide. It looks like you are attempting to initialise the SDK without parameters, which is covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters). Basically, you need to set an environment variable (via `export` in your terminal, not `.env` files) called `FIREBASE_CONFIG` which is either a path to a JSON file containing your config information or is a JSON object containing your config information.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @beardo, I was under the imipression you could run Firebase locally without specifyihng a process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET .  That is my intention anyway.  Let me know if there is something else I have to do to make it so that Firebase isn't looking for this.